# Используя QTimer получаю странную ошибку(argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLabel')?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtimer

Есть код, где я должен постоянно читать текст. Для этого я решил использовать `QTimer`, но получил ошибку

> argument 1 has unexpected type 'QLabel.

Как ее исправить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                           
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
import os

word_count = ""

class Ui_Micro(object):
    def setupUi(self, Micro):
        Micro.setObjectName("Micro")
        Micro.resize(330, 233)
        self.microphone = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)
        self.microphone.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-40, -10, 241, 261))
        self.microphone.setText("")
        self.microphone.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("microphone.png"))
        self.microphone.setObjectName("microphone")
        self.word_count_info = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)
        self.word_count_info.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 171, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.word_count_info.setFont(font)
        self.word_count_info.setObjectName("word_count_info")
        self.word_count = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)
        self.word_count.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.word_count.setFont(font)
        self.word_count.setObjectName("word_count")

        self.retranslateUi(Micro)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Micro)

    def retranslateUi(self, Micro):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Micro.setWindowTitle(_translate("Micro", "Microphone"))
        self.word_count_info.setText(_translate("Micro", "Кол-во сказанных слов:"))
        self.word_count.setText(_translate("Micro", "0"))


class Microphone(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Micro):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)       
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.word_count_info)
        self.timer.start(2)

    def word_count_info(self):
        with open("word_count.txt", mode="r") as txt:
            word_count = read.word_count()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.press:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.last_pos)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = True

        self.last_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = False

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,1), 1000))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Microphone()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас

`self.word_count_info` - это `self.word_count_info = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)`,

а в `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.word_count_info)` нужно указать метод.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                           
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
import os

# ??? word_count = ""

class Ui_Micro(object):
    def setupUi(self, Micro):
        Micro.setObjectName("Micro")
        Micro.resize(330, 233)
        self.microphone = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)
        self.microphone.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-40, -10, 241, 261))
        self.microphone.setText("")
        self.microphone.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("microphone.png"))
        self.microphone.setObjectName("microphone")
        self.word_count_info = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)
        self.word_count_info.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 171, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.word_count_info.setFont(font)
        self.word_count_info.setObjectName("word_count_info")
        self.word_count = QtWidgets.QLabel(Micro)
        self.word_count.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.word_count.setFont(font)
        self.word_count.setObjectName("word_count")

        self.retranslateUi(Micro)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Micro)

    def retranslateUi(self, Micro):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Micro.setWindowTitle(_translate("Micro", "Microphone"))
        self.word_count_info.setText(_translate("Micro", "Кол-во сказанных слов:"))
        self.word_count.setText(_translate("Micro", "0"))


class Microphone(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Micro):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        self.setupUi(self)
        
#        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)       
#        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
#        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.word_count_info)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.func_word_count_info)             # func_word_count_info
        
        self.timer.start(2000)

#    def word_count_info(self):
    def func_word_count_info(self):                                        # func_word_count_info
        with open("word_count.txt", mode="r") as txt:
#            word_count = read.word_count()
            word_count = txt.read()                                         # +++
        #print(f'word_count = {word_count}')
        self.word_count.setNum(len(word_count.split()))                     # +++

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.press:
            self.move(event.globalPos() - self.last_pos)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = True

        self.last_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.press = False

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,10,11), 1000))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Microphone()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]